# Fun with numbers: solve A to E

Tags: number-theory

A, B, C, D and E are five distinct non-negative integers no greater than 99. Can you figure out their values based on the following simple clues?

- Not all of the five numbers have the same parity
- A + E is even
- B is A cubed
- C is the least among the five numbers
- D is B divided by 2
- E is prime

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> A = 4
>  B = 64
>  C = 1
>  D = 32
>  E = 2.

Explanation:

> D is B divided by 2 means B is even.
>  This and B is A cubed means A is even.
>  This and A + E is even means E is even.
>  This and E is prime means E = 2 since it's the only even prime.
>  C is the least among the five numbers means C is smaller than 2. So C = 1 or 0.
>  Coming back to B is a perfect cube of an even number and it's below 100 it means B can be 8 or 64.
>  For B to be 8 A should be 2, but that's not possible since E = 2.
>  So B = 64. This gets you A = 4 and D = 32.
>  A, B, D, E are all even. This means C has to be odd. So C = 1

Recap to see that all of them fit:

> $A + E = 4 + 2 = 6$ which is even  - checked
>  B is A cubed => $64 = 4^3$ - checked
>  $C = 1 < 2 < 4 < 32 < 64$ - checked
>  D is B divided by 2: $32 = \frac{64}{2}$ - checked
>  E is prime. 2 is prime - checked.

Comment: Wow, that was fast. I'm posting this here as a P.O.C. of a mystery geocache and it seems I might want to crank up the difficulty gears a bit for a suitable challenge. Excellent work!

Comment: Thanks. I edited the answer with the explanation. See if it is what you expected.

Comment: @kviiri I think people here at PuzzlingSE are a notch above the average geocache searcher. I think the difficutly level you have is nice for your application.

Answer (score 6):

**Final answer:**

> A = 4, B = 64, C = 1, D = 32, E = 2

**Explanation:**

- A + E is even: A and E have the same parity
- B is A cubed: B and A have the same parity
- D is B divided by 2: B is even

> - From these statements, E is even. From the last statement, "E is prime", E must an even prime, so E = 2.
> - C is the least among all numbers and is the only odd integer, so to be less than 2 it must be 1.
> - A can't be 2 because it is distinct from E, but it can't be larger than 5 because B = A cubed is less than 100, so A is 4.
> - This leaves B = A cubed = 64, and D = B divided by 2 = 32.